# .htaccess URL rewrite issue with query parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess rule that goes like this

```
RewriteRule ^account/(.*) myaccount.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

This works fine for URLs like `https://www.example.com/account/abcd`.
However, now I want to pass query parameters to this URL, something like `https://www.example.com/account/abcd?ab=1&cd=2`.

Can't figure out the exact `.htaccess` rule that can accommodate this. 
Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^account/(.*) myaccount.php?p=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

With QSA:

> **QSA|qsappend**
>   When the replacement URI contains a query string, the
>   default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query
>   string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA]
>   flag causes the query strings to be combined.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html